# Laravel - How to check current month inside an date string?

Tags: php, database, laravel, orm, back

So, I have a field on my database that keeps the date, just like the `created_at` field, year-month-day format.

I need to create a method to do a query to return all results where month = current month we are living. How can I check this on laravel?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`Model::whereMonth('field', Carbon::now()->month)->get();`